# Check if 3D point inside a box

Tags: c++, 3d, geometry, glm-math

I have a box which consists of 8 vertices and may be scaled or rotated in any direction so I apply the transformation matrix for vertices each transformation, I have center, size and directions on X,Y and Z from center, how can I check if any 3D point is inside the box ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have:

```
vec3 center; // Center of the box.
vec3 dx, dy, dz; // X,Y, and Z directions, normalized.
vec3 half; // Box size in each dimension, divided by 2.

vec3 point; // Point to test.
```

Then the test is as simple as:

```
vec3 d = point - center;
bool inside = abs(dot(d, dx)) <= half.x &&
              abs(dot(d, dy)) <= half.y &&
              abs(dot(d, dz)) <= half.z;
```

---

The primary property of dot product is that fact that
`X⋅Y == |X|⋅|Y|⋅cos(angle_formed_by_X_and_Y)`.

If `Y` is normalized, then `X⋅Y` essentially gives you the length of the projection of `X` onto `Y` (which is negative iff the angle formed by `X` and `Y` is obtuse). Once you have the projection lengths, you just need to compare their absolute values with corresponding half-extents of your box.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation, I implemented it and worked very well

Comment: Hi, could you please explain what dx, dy, and dz are? What is in these directions?

Comment: @Biiiiiird Those are essentially normals to the sides of the box (vectors of unit length perpendicular to the sides).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat So dx, dy, dz are relative or local to the box itself, not the global axes x, y, and z? I can simply calculate this by finding the normals to 3 sides of the box? Also to calculate for eg. half.x, this is also local? Calculate the max and min x values in the vertices, subtract the two and divide by 2? Hoping my understanding is correct.

Comment: @Biiiiiird dx,dy,dz don't depend on box position, yes. They do depend on it's rotation. Yes, just calculate the normals. I'm not sure how half.x/y/z can be local or global, it's just the box size divided by two.